# Choose a machine learning algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, svm, knn, naivebayes

I am dealing with a problem to implement a machine learning algorithm.

Working : 
￼[Click to see Map of City](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuvSF.png)

---

Assume the above given Map has 12 Signals. Each signal has a Router [ Dot ] . Router get the traffic count.Traffic count is then added to DB at server-side. This traffic count is sent to the handheld device held by cop at each signal.  After every 5 minutes the count of all routers is made 0.

Now here comes the main crux of system. When a vehicle is detected and validated at server it may be ‘Valid’ or ‘Invalid’ vehicle. Now if it ‘Invalid’ Vehicle then it must be caught..!! But how to catch a vehicle ? Now lets take an example.

As shown in diagram 
    1. Invalid Vehicle ‘A’ is detected at G-Router **[G=GREEN]**
    2. So it may go to all possible R-Router’s **[R=RED]**
    3. Now if count at each router is

```
         - R-Router 1 = 23 

         - R-Router 2 = 16 

         - R-Router 3 = 31 

         - R-Router 4 = 47 

         - G-Router = 19
```

4. And distance between each router is

```
    - R-Router 1 —> G-Router = 3 K.M.

    - R-Router 2 —> G-Router = 5 K.M

    - R-Router 3 —> G-Router = 2 K.M

    - R-Router 4 —> G-Router = 1 K.M
```

5. So by above given data calculate the TIME required.
    6. This TIME is then sent to handheld devices connected to all of the R-Router’s
I want **PROBABILISTIC TIME** at which the vehicle may come at each R-Router respectively. So by using traffic data of all the R-Router’s and G-Router i want to develop  algorithm.

```
Available :

        - Count of traffic at each Router/Signal [Dynamically changes after each 5 minutes]
        - Distance Between each Router
Find : 

        - Probabilistic Time Required for ‘A’ vehicle to reach any given router.
```

Comment: Why you what to use a machine learning algorithm? This is a Graph problem. For example dijkstra. dijkstra  is also the base for the most way finder algorithms an maps.

Comment: @Denis Kohl . Yeah but my problem isnt solved by Dijkstra's Algorithm. My aim is to find Time Required for a vehicle. And especially Machine Learning because i want my algorithm to learn. For ex: If count of R1= 13 and R2 = 43, distance is 3 K.M. and time taken by vehicle 'X' is 6.7min. Now if next time vehicle 'Y' comes and count at Rx and Ry is same as R1 and R2 and so as their distance then algorithm should return 6.7min with probability. So i want to classify the traffic count on basis of their distance.

Comment: I don't see you argument. But you can use GMM http://www.ics.uci.edu/~smyth/courses/cs274/notes/EMnotes.pdf
To learn what is the best way, if x or y